# Troubleshooting azure website internal error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am getting an error message on my website:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

How do I troubleshoot this. I can't find the log file. Please help.

Comment: If its a .Net site, may be changing customErrors element setting in web.config would help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: Sorry didn't mention. I'm using Node.js.

Comment: Make sure the site works locally...

Answer (score 1):

Some information on debugging youe node.js site on Azure websites can be found here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-debug/
and here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StreamingDiagnosticsTraceLoggingFromTheAzureCommandLinePlusGlimpse.aspx

To enable application logging instead of updating the iisnode.yml file, you can also use the portal and from the Website/CONFIGURE tab you can enable application logging to file system.

Also look into: http://blog.azure.com/2014/03/28/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about-2/ for an easy way to see the log files without installing any tools.